# Memcache + Shared Hosting with Multiple Websites

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, memcached

so my situation is I'm using Shared Hosting for my eCommerce websites (Wordpress) and I just found out about Memcache and Redis. My hosting provider is Interserver, and they said I couldn't use Redis, so my websites have to use Memcache.

Inside my database, I have 1 folder named ".memcache" with 1 file named "memcached.sock". They told me I can use 1 **Memcached hostname:port** for multiple websites, I asked if I should create each memcache for each website so they won't overwrite each other's caches, and they said no, because they said, and I quote:

> You only need to set the socket once for the account. It is account wise setting not domain wise.

So what should I do now? I read something about prefix the keys or instances, but I don't really understand anything on this field!

I want to use Memcache on my websites and they won't cause any problem like overwrite each other!

Comment: *"I want to use Memcache on my websites"* What for?

Comment: Have you looked into how to use a cache first. If you can write some code to show how each site will use it, then it can be adapted to use a prefix quite easily (what this prefix is may be the next issue).

Comment: You store key/value pairs in a cache, like `x = 42`.  If your cache is shared between 2 sites, then `x` on one site might overwrite the `x` from the other site.  Maybe you could work around that by prefixing the keys for everything on site A with `A`, and everything on site B with `B`.  Then when site B does `Bx = 3.14`, it won't clobber `Ax = 42`.

Comment: Your question as it is is too open ended and broad for SO and is likely to be closed.  Try searching for and going through some tutorials, pick something that suits your project, and have a go at implementing something.  If you have trouble that's the time to ask a question on SO, showing the code you're having trouble with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, I want to use Memcache because I want to reduce my ecommerce pages load time.

Thanks everyone, I'll look into it more, and sorry for the broad question! I didn't know much so I thought I could post it here for some guidances (and I did get some)

Comment: And how exactly will Memcache "reduce my ecommerce pages load time"? What will you store in Memcache? How will WordPress use it?

Comment: My websites are eCommerce, but besides products' related content, I added many other elements from PHP, JS, HTML and CSS. Since they're always the same, I figure I can cache them on memcache? And I read that memcache reads and pulls data from it's cache faster than MySQL pulling the same data (correct me if it's wrong). Currently, I'm using W3 Total Cache and they have a section to use memcache simply by inputing my "Memcached hostname:port", but it's too simple and I don't know if I need to learn more about memcache and write more rules inside or it automatically cache and pull keys/values.